# Only New Products showing in Category Pages

Tags: products

I've Fresh Magento installation. I've added magento sample data into db, and installed magento using that DB. It didn't show any products into category page. After several hit and tries I figured out that if I mark a product as NEW, then it starts showing up. I've tried different methods to get rid of this problem, but nothing seems to work. This is what I've tried doing:

- Reinstalled my Windows 7
- Fresh installed xampp
- Fresh installed magento
- Connected it with Database of dummy data
- To check if the problem is with my theme, I've used default theme

I've checked the checklist on [this stackoverflow asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category), but still have the problem. The problem is not only confounded to category pages, only the products who are marked as NEW will display in 'related products' block, and on homepage. As if products which are not marked as NEW are invisible.

Can anyone please point out what could be the possible problem.

Comment: Did you rebuild the indexes after installing over the sample data? (System->Index management)

Comment: @Marius No I didn't. Just did. And it worked! If you could add your comment as an answer. I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Magento over the sample data a full reindex is required in order to have to associations between categories and products in the correct format.
That can be done from `System->Index management`.